# Django Form Submission Error

Tags: django, forms

I have this recurring problem with form submission in Django, and the frustrating part is that I'm not sure how to interpret what's happening. Essentially I have different pages with form submissions on them. Some of them work as following

```
localhost/page/formpage--> localhost/page/receivingpage
```

which is what I expect. Othertimes, it goes to a page like this

```
localhost/page/formpage--> localhost/page/formpage/recevingpage
```

and the screen shows a blank form page, which is not what I expect. I'm not sure how to interpret this, and I'm not sure where to look for errors in my code. I think I don't fully understand what's going on when I submit a form, how does it generate a URL after I press 'submit'?

Edit: here is my html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<div>
<p>Entry Form</p>
<form action= "user" method="post" >
{% csrf_token %}
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username"" /></p>
<p><label for="id_password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</div>
</html>
```

I suspect it isn't the form, I have it on another application and it works... the trouble is I don't know if it's the view, the template, or w/e, so I'll update the post with info as people request it.

Comment: its too hard to guess what might be wrong - You can see if you are missing a prefix of `/` Where you have a false call

Comment: Can you post the template where the `<form>` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `{% url %}` tag is the proper way to do. Your problem can also be solved by adding a forward slash `/` to the `action` attribute like this:

```
<form action="/user" method="post" >
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting... using the slash brings me to localhost/user, instead of what I thought would be localhost/formpage/user (the action appending itself to the sending page)... is there a way to use that relative path, to append the action onto the sending page's URL?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, if you use the slash, the rest will append to the root address, if you don't, it will append to the current address (relative)

Comment: Nevermind, I don't think there's really that much utility by using a relative vs. absolute URL, and I'll cross the relative bridge when I need to. I'd just create new pages for each form instance that I need. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend putting in an `action` using the `url` template tag.  With that, you will know for certain where the form is going to end up:

```
<form action="{% url 'user-url-name' %}" method="post">
```

The `url` tag will be an absolute url.  Without this, you're going to end up at a relative url depending on where in your application the user submits the form, which can be quite confusing  during development and not entirely correct.